# Bash script for opening terminal

Tags: bash, terminal

I have this script in my file.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
gnome-terminal -e 'ssh user@server'
```

If i start it using terminal `./file.sh` it works, but when i start it using File Manager (double click on the icon) nothing happens.

How can I make bash script which run command in terminal and open it?

Comment: `start it using File Manager (GUI)`, how?

Comment: Double click on the icon

Comment: `#!/bin/bash
start /bin/bash -e 'ssh user@server'` ?

Comment: After double click, nothing happens, no terminal window shows

Comment: `Double click on the icon` what icon? is it a desktop launcher or are you trying to run the script by double clicking? It may also depend on your file manager if it really allows users to run scripts by double clicking or not.

Comment: Icon of file (file.sh) located in home directory (Ubuntu), i just want to double click on file.sh and then open terminal window with 'ssh user@server' command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

**UPDATE**

If you are running Ubuntu with the Nautilus Filebrowser, you can click

`Edit->Preferences`

from the menubar, and change the behavior of executable files in the *Behavior* tab of File Preferences.

This implies that your script is executable (see my original answer below)

---

**Original Answer**

Did you make your script executable by applying

`chmod u+x yourscript.sh`

or

`chmod +x yourscript.sh`

to it in your terminal?

Keep in mind that `chmod u+x` grands execution rights to the owner of the
script whereas `chmod +x` will grand execution rights to every user on your system!

Comment: Doesnþt help, i have permissions, it works in terminal, but when i double click on icon, it doesn shows terminal

Comment: From your command "gnome-terminal" I assume you are running this on linux? If so, this similar question from the AskUbuntu community might help you! http://askubuntu.com/questions/465531/how-to-make-a-shell-file-execute-by-double-click

Comment: Yes i have Ubuntu, but i would like to start it from folder and not from Desktop

Comment: If you are running Ubuntu with the Nautilus FIlebrowser, you can click Edit->Preferences from the menubar, and change the behavior of executable files in the "Behavior" tab of File Preferences.

Comment: Yes it works, thank you, if you edit your post with that behavior settings i will give you upvote